# How to scroll horizontally extreme left when scroll bar is in middle of the page using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, horizontal-scrolling

On page, the horizontal scroll bar is in middle and I need to scroll it to extreme left to see the first column

I have tried for different ways as seen below:

```
WebElement userPhase = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ag-header-row']//div[@col-id='user_Phasing_Attribute_1']"));
actions.moveToElement(userPhase).build().perform();



JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement Element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("VBScript")); // This will scroll the page Horizontally till the element is found
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", Element);



JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("<document.getElementByxpath('//div[@col-id='user_Phasing_Attribute_1']').scrollLeft += 250>", "");


((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(-2000,0)");
```

Comment: I'm not a java-script expert, but as far as I know there are no methods available to get element by xpath `document.getElementByxpath`

Comment: @AppuMistri yes its something .evaluate but not working through that as well

Comment: Its better if you can add screenshot here. is it inside of iframe or something ? if so try to shift iframe and scroll.

Comment: Sorry @Devdun not possible for me to add screenshot due to some security issue. But it is not iframe its normal page. and i also tried ROBOT keypress but the same also is not happening